# How to implement accumulation by Java8 stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

Input stream:

```
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Expect result stream:

```
Stream.of(1, 3, 6, 10)
```

How to implement accumulation by Java8 stream API

Comment: You'd be better off using a for-loop here.

Comment: Yes, @ernest_k is correct. However I think OP aims at the general understanding of how it could be done.

Comment: Whenever you have side effects with a stream, which is *not* parallel, then you should simply use for-loops

Comment: A Stream is not an end in itself. Define an actual result.

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated (and I feel obliged to add) is that this is not a good practice. In cases like this, a `for`-loop is preferable, unless you are using Streams as return types or parameters.

The main issue with this is, that not all streams are required to be either sequential or ordered. A parallel stream may not handle the results in the expected order and mess things up. You way of creating the `Stream` suggests, that you have a sequential stream, so I will assume, you leave it that way. Then a possible solution may be:

```java
AtomicInteger sum = new AtomicInteger(0);
Stream<Integer> expectedStream = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4).map(i -> sum.addAndGet(i));
```

`expectedStream` is now a stream providing elements `{ 1, 3, 6, 10 }` as expected, assuming no outer meddling with the `sum`.
This solution builds on the workaround, that external values (though required to be effectively final) can be modified indirectly by reference. You can just as well use an array `int[1]`.

Comment: I earlier wrote `sum.getAndAdd` which is incorrect. Please be aware of the change!

Comment: The stream referenced by `expectedStream` is *not* “a stream of `{ 1, 3, 6, 10 }`”. It’s a stream encapsulating a *behavior* which has not taken place yet. Just consider what happens, when I call `sum.set(42)` after that, but before `expectedStream` is used. You don’t need to point to parallel processing, for example uses that can break it. What happens when you use, e.g. `.skip(3).forEach(System.out::println)`? With the *current implementation*, it happens to do the desired thing. Will it continue to work with future versions or alternative JREs? Nobody knows.

Comment: While it is true, that the `Stream` does not contain the values `{ 1, 3, 6, 10 }` (thank you for that clarification), the `skip` example still works, because the `skip` is only applied after the individual sums are calculated. Just assume it weren't so... if you wanted to parse lines from a file and skip the first 10, you couldn't, because the skip would optimize the first 10 accesses away, disregarding the fact, that they might change external state, e.g. an underlying `InputStream`.
If you were to change the code I wrote, or insert things in between, then of course, you can break anything.

Comment: The Stream API makes no guarantees about the state of the source. All that matters, is what is required to provide the requested result. Of course, when the source is processing the lines of a file, there is no way around identifying them to skip them. This doesn’t apply to a random access source like `Stream.of(…)`. For example, when you chain `count()`, the `AtomicInteger` does not get touched in Java 9 or newer, while it is modified in Java 8. There is no guaranty that the side effect does happen and future versions may add more optimizations. It’s not hard to imagine a more efficient skip…

Comment: `count` is a good example of behavior changing between JDKs. And I admit that a fundamental possibility exists that `Stream` may change in such a way, that the results of the above snippet may break. I will heed the warning and take greater care of my own code as well, regarding streams (though I rarely use them anyway).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is, simply don't. Whenever you have to keep track of something, e.g. the previous sum, **don't** use `Stream`s. They are not made for statefulness, they were intended to simply apply some independent conversions and filters to a potential endless amount of elements.

For your problem, I can't see why you **wouldn't** want to use a simple loop.

```
int[] yourInts = {1, 2, 3, 4};
for(int i = 0, sum = 0; i < yourInts.length; i++) {
    sum += yourInts[i];
    yourInts[i] = sum;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the better solution - thus upvoted, though not the answer to the question ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that it is ordered stream then you can do it without accumulator. With this formula:

```java
Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4)
    .map(i -> i * (i + 1) / 2)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```